# HTMLPurifier allow attributes

Tags: attributes, htmlpurifier

I'm having troubles making HTMLPurifier do not filter tag attributes but without success until now and im going crazy.

```
    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8');
    $config->set('Core.CollectErrors', true);
    $config->set('HTML.TidyLevel', 'medium');
    $config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional');
    $config->set('URI.DisableExternalResources', false);

    $config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'table[border|width|style],tbody,tr,td,th,img[style|src|alt],span[style],p[style],ul,ol,li,strong,em,sup,sub');

    $PHTML = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    echo htmlspecialchars($PHTML->purify($html));

    // The input string:
    "Some <span style="text-decoration: underline;">cool text</span> <img src="http://someurl.com/images/logo.png" alt="" />.

    // The output string:
    "Some <span>cool text</span> <img src="%5C" alt="" />.
```

I want to allow the given attributes for specified elements which are defined in HTML.Allowed option.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off magic quotes. (Note the %5C)

Comment: I try it but now it is outputing: Some <span>cool text</span> <img src="\" alt="" />

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late suggestion, but I've run into a similar issue with HTMLPurifier stripping *style* attributes even though they were configured in the **HTML.Allowed** setting.

The solution I found requires that you also configure **CSS.AllowedProperties** which looks a bit like this:

```
$config->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', 'text-align,text-decoration,width,height');
```

Use this in conjunction with HTML.Allowed:

```
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'img[src|alt|style],span[style]');
```

I hope someone else finds this useful, [you can read more about CSS.AllowedProperties here](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#CSS.AllowedProperties).