How to prevent HTMLPurifier from sanitizing the inline style attribute?
I'm using HTMLPurifier to sanitize HTML, but I want to prevent any changes to the inline style attribute. Specifically, I don't want HTMLPurifier to modify or sanitize the values of the style attribute while purifying the HTML.
Here's a sample code:
require_once 'ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$dirty_html = '<div style="background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);"> How configure HTMLPurifier to prevent sanitize of Inline-style Attribute ? </div>';
// I want to prevent any change done by purify on style Attribute values
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);

// But in $clean_html div style value becomes: style="background-color:rgb(0,240,240);"
echo $clean_html;


How can I configure HTMLPurifier to skip sanitizing the style attribute ?

Are you using the latest version of the library?

Failed to reproduce with online demo

@shingo The htmlpurifier.org site seems to be outdated. The news page stops at 2017 with version 4.9.3. The github project is at version 4.18.0.

@Olivier This is quite surprising, but I tried 4.18.0 just now and it still yielded the same result.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515111/htmlpurifier-allow-attributes
Seems to answer the question

For what it's worth, this is not sanitisation. Replacing 240 with 0 in the red component of a CSS colour does not accomplish anything from security standpoint. I presume it's a bug (the project does not seem to be under very active maintenance at this moment). If you want to disable sanitisation as a sort of workaround, just be careful you don't end up with broken HTML or XSS issues.
